# Pass and loop Strongly Types Data List to WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I am coming from MVC background where I can pass the model data list from controller to view more in structure manner. I need to now how I can pass storgly typed model data from C# class to page.

I am using ASP.NET 3.5

### Model Class

```
  public class RolesModel
{
    public RolesModel() { }

    public long RoleID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have managed to bring list data in aspx.cs class... how I can loop form data in aspx page???

### Roles.aspx.cs class

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<RolesModel> roleList = new List<RolesModel>();

        roleList = RoleDefinationRelay.GetAllRoles(null);

    }
```

### aspx

```
<table>
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <td>Role ID</td>
                               <td>Title</td>
                               <td>Description</td>
                               <td>Created Date</td>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <%foreach(var item in  %>???????????
                           </tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
```

Comment: do I no need to send variable reference to view page???

Comment: Based on that terminology, I'd say go read a basic ASPX WebForms tutorial... Generally you'd use a repeater on the layout page to loop over a property that exists in the code behind.

Comment: I am here to guideline not learning a-z. if you don't want to tell is fine ...

Comment: What "guideline" are you looking for then? "How to output some variable in WebForms"? That's pretty basic, try searching. See my updated comment above for some relevant terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is using ASP:Repeater control. Hope this helps

**in your .aspx**

```
<form runat="server"> 
<asp:Repeater id="rptRoles" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
   <td>Role ID</td>
   <td>Title</td>
   <td>Description</td>
   <td>Created Date</td>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
    <td><%#Eval("RoleID")%></td>
    <td><%#Eval("Title")%></td>
    <td><%#Eval("Description")%></td>
    <td><%#Eval("CreatedDate")%></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(!Page.IsPostBack){
        List<RolesModel> roleList = new List<RolesModel>();
        roleList = RoleDefinationRelay.GetAllRoles(null);
        //set data source of repeater and bind
         rptRoles.DataSource = roleList;
         rptRoles.DataBind();
    }

 }
```

Comment: ARRRG - SO needs to implement a "Someone else is typing almost exactly the same answer as you at the moment..." feature :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are thinking about it from an MVC point of view - I had the same issue in reverse because my background in webforms!

in webforms you dont bind your data that way (you can - but it takes more work and its not really the accepted way)

What you need is in your aspx is a server control that will handle the looping and rendering for you - for this example im going to use a gridview because its quick, but if you need more control over your HTML you should use a repeater or a listview.

Your code behind is almost there...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<RolesModel> roleList = new List<RolesModel>();

    roleList = RoleDefinationRelay.GetAllRoles(null);

    //Bind the gridview
    gvRoles.DataSource = roleList;
    gvRoles.DataBind();
}
```

then in your aspx page:
    < asp:GridView id="gvRoles" runat="server" />

What is happening here is in the page_load you are getting the data, assigning it to a servercontrol (Setting the datasource) and telling the control to render it (Databind)

When the page is processed your code will fire, getting your list of roles which will be passed over to the gridview which knows that its got to generate a table with a row for each item in your list and a column for each property for each of the items...

As I said above if you need more control over the HTML that it outputs have a look at a repeater and the ListView controls.

Hope that helps!

Comment: many thanks ... that is really helpful, I aware danger as my mind so much thinking of MVC way... sometime you don't need detail if you have already work in one of patter but just right direction ....